# Is there a more pythonic/"better" way to do this? (Removing overlapping cubes from a list of cubes)

Tags: python, list, geometry

I have a class cuboid:

```
class Cuboid:
    #a rectangular solid
    def __init__(self, (x0, y0, z0), (x1, y1, z1)):

        self.z0 = min(z0,z1)
        self.x0 = min(x0,x1)
        self.y0 = min(y0,y1)
        self.z1 = max(z0,z1)
        self.x1 = max(x0,x1)
        self.y1 = max(y0,y1)

        self.start = (self.x0, self.y0, self.z0)
        self.end = (self.x1, self.y1, self.z1)


    def centre(self):
        center_x = (self.x0 + self.x1)/2
        center_y = (self.y0 + self.y1)/2
        center_z = (self.z0 + self.z1)/2
        return (center_x, center_y, center_z)

    def intersects(self, other):
        #returns true if this cuboid intersects with another one
        if self == other:
            return True
        else:
            return (
                        self.x0 <= other.x1
                        and self.x1 >= other.x0
                        and self.y0 <= other.y1
                        and self.y1 >= other.y0
                        and self.z0 <= other.z1
                        and self.z1 >= other.z0
                    )
```

I create a list of ten cubes with random co-ordinates:

```
cubelist = []
for i in range(10):
    cube = Cuboid((rand.randint(1,80), rand.randint(1,80), rand.randint(1,3)), (rand.randint(1,80), rand.randint(1,80), rand.randint(5,9)))
    cubelist.append(cube)
```

What I want to be able to do is to take this list and remove from it all the intersecting cubes.(I could check for intersection when I call append, but I'd like to see if I can do it this way too)

The only way I've been able to do is with something like this:

```
def cube_untangler(cubelist)

    cubelist1 = [x for x in cubelist]
    cubelist2 = [x for x in cubelist]

    for x in cubelist:
        cubelist1.remove(x)
        if any(x.intersects(y) for y in cubelist1):
            cubelist2.remove(x)


    return cubelist2
```

It feels a bit clumsy to me, though. I tried using list comprehensions earlier, but I couldn't get them to remove all of the intersecting cubes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that your "intersects" function even works. I think it actually returns true only if the contains the other one.

Comment: Agreed-- presumably, `a.instersects(b)` should equal `b.intersects(a)`, which is not the case with your function.

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your intersection function works as you like, I think you can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to do this.

Essentially, calling itertools.combinations(cubelist, 2) will generate all possible pairs of cubs in the cubelist. So something like

```
for cube1, cube2 in itertools.combinations(cubelist, 2):
    # I'm adding this since I'm not sure what happens when you remove elements as you go
    if cube1 in cubelist and cube2 in cubelist:
        if cube1.intersects(cube2):
            cubelist.remove(cube2)
```